# Prove that $a^3+b^3+c^3+d^3\ge\frac{1}{2}$

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization

If $a,b,c,d\ge -1$ and $a+b+c+d=2$ prove that $a^3+b^3+c^3+d^3\ge \frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Hey there - normally on this site we encourage users to tell us how far they've gotten, show us what method they've tried, and allow us to help them past the point at which they've gotten stuck. People tend not to like answering questions with no details provided.

Comment: @Abdel Alla I solved your problem. If you want to see my solution, show please your attempts.